# Getting undefined reference related to levelDB in C++ program despite including the library in QT Creator (in Ubuntu 16.04)

Tags: c++, qt-creator, undefined-reference, leveldb

These are the errors that I'm getting while building the c++ project in QT Creator:

```
error: undefined reference to `leveldb::DestroyDB(std::string const&, leveldb::Options const&)' 
error: undefined reference to `leveldb::RepairDB(std::string const&, leveldb::Options const&)'    
error: undefined reference to `leveldb::DB::Open(leveldb::Options const&, std::string const&, leveldb::DB**)'
error: undefined reference to `leveldb::Status::ToString() const'
```

Earlier, additionally, I was getting tens of similar libcurl undefined reference errors, but I fixed the errors after using the "add library" and selecting the "System Library" option, which automatically included the following line to the .pro file:

```
unix|win32: LIBS += -lcurl
```

So, I tried the same thing for leveldb, which has automatically included the following line in the .pro file:

```
unix|win32: LIBS += -lleveldb
```

But despite that, the errors are still there.

Comment: Have you installed the development package of leveldb?

Comment: Yes, have tried that multiple times.. and I guess it gets installed.

Comment: In fact, the line "LIBS += -lleveldb" gets added automatically when I point out the libleveldb.so file contained in the usr/local/lib directory.

Comment: I'm facing the same issue and I guess this is related to C++11 ABI compatibility.